# Double look-ahead assertion in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I know that look ahead assertions matches based on the condition. But suddenly I was struck by this double look-ahead assertion.

```
>>> a = compile(r'a(?=b)(?=c)')
>>> b = a.findall('abc')
>>> b
[]
```

Then what it matches. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this does not match anything because you match `a` and then assert that what follows should be `b` and then again assert that it should be `c`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Is that the (?=c) is in such a way that it must follow 'a'.  'a' must be followed by 'b' and 'c' at the same time. That is impossible so that it matches nothing. Did I understood it right ?

Comment: `compile(r'a(?=b(?=c))')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are matching `a` and [assert](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) that after a, there should be a `b`. That assertions succeeds.

But after that, you assert that what comes after the `a` should be a `c`. That assertion fails, so there will be no match.

This for example [`a(?=b)`](https://regex101.com/r/ehokah/1) will succeed and matches `a`.

This [`a(?=c)`](https://regex101.com/r/ehokah/2) will not succeed because there is no c after a.

To assert that there is `bc` after a you might use [`a(?=bc)`](https://regex101.com/r/ehokah/3) or an assertion inside an assertion [`a(?=b(?=c))`](https://regex101.com/r/ehokah/4) as [@Keyur Potdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7832176/keyur-potdar) points out.